# Testing Vue.js Component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, vue.js

I'd like to test a Vue.js component, and I'm failing at that. Simply put, I'm setting a component property, and I want to assert that it is set correctly. If that matters, the module is loaded with exports, and the JS is output using Webpack.

```
// component
exports = module.exports = {};

module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return {
      active: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    'close': function () {
       console.log(this.active); // -> true
       this.active = false;
       console.log(this.active); // -> false
    }
  }
};

// component-test
var modal = require('../../resources/src/js/components/_component.js');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('close()', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    modal.data.active = true;
  });
  it('should set modal to inactive', function () {
    console.log(modal.data.active); // -> true
    modal.methods.close();
    console.log(modal.data.active); // -> true
    assert.equal(modal.data.active, false);
  });
});
```

Comment: so what is actually failing? what's the output of your tests? have you check  the [vue js guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Unit_Testing) about testing?

Comment: also check the [webpack example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader-example) on github, there are some test defined there, with karma + jasmine + phantomjs

Answer (score 6):

This should give you a hint on how to load vue components when testing;

```
var modalComponent = require('../../resources/src/js/components/_component.js');
var assert = require('assert');         

 //load the component with a vue instance
vm = new Vue({
    template: '<div><test v-ref:test-component></test></div>',
    components: {
        'test': modalComponent
    }
}).$mount();

var modal = vm.$refs.testComponent;

describe('close()', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        modal.active = true;
    });

    it('should set modal to inactive', function () {
        console.log(modal.active); // -> true
        modal.close();
        console.log(modal.active); // -> false
        assert.equal(modal.active, false);
    });
});
```

Comment: for some reason, running methods like this makes PhantomJS timeout.

`PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 4 DISCONNECTED (10.003 secs / 0 secs)`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/eddyerburgh/avoriaz is now the official testing library for Vue.js checkout the documentation on getting setup to make assertions on your components https://eddyerburgh.gitbooks.io/avoriaz/content/